# Azure Easy Table: Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, azure, entity, azure-mobile-services

## Question

How do I solve this error message for an Easy Table that I've created in the Microsoft Azure Portal? This error occurs when I call `MobileServiceClient.SyncContext.PushAsync`:

```
OperationKind: Insert

Error Result: {
  "error": "request entity too large"
}
```

## NuGet Packages

I am using the following NuGet Packages:

- Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client v3.1.0
- Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore v3.1.0

## Code

```
    static bool _isInitialized;
    static MobileServiceClient _mobileService;

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync<T>() where T : EntityData
    {
        await Initialize<T>();

        await SyncItemsAsync<T>();

        return await _mobileService.GetSyncTable<T>().ToEnumerableAsync();
    }

    public static async Task<T> GetItem<T>(string id) where T : EntityData
    {
        await Initialize<T>();

        await SyncItemsAsync<T>();

        return await _mobileService.GetSyncTable<T>().LookupAsync(id);
    }

    public static async Task AddItemAsync<T>(T item) where T : EntityData
    {
        await Initialize<T>();

        await _mobileService.GetSyncTable<T>().InsertAsync(item);
        await SyncItemsAsync<T>();
    }

    public static async Task UpdateItemAsync<T>(T item) where T : EntityData
    {
        await Initialize<T>();

        await _mobileService.GetSyncTable<T>().UpdateAsync(item);
        await SyncItemsAsync<T>();
    }

    public static async Task RemoveItemAsync<T>(T item) where T : EntityData
    {
        await Initialize<T>();

        await _mobileService.GetSyncTable<T>().DeleteAsync(item);
        await SyncItemsAsync<T>();
    }

    static async Task SyncItemsAsync<T>() where T : EntityData
    {
        await Initialize<T>();

        try
        {
            await _mobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
            await _mobileService.GetSyncTable<T>().PullAsync($"all{typeof(T).Name}", _mobileService.GetSyncTable<T>().CreateQuery());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Error during Sync occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    async static Task Initialize<T>() where T : EntityData
    {
        if (_isInitialized)
            return;

        _mobileService = new MobileServiceClient(AzureConstants.AppServiceUrl);

        await ConfigureOnlineOfflineSync<T>();

        _isInitialized = true;
    }

    static async Task ConfigureOnlineOfflineSync<T>() where T : EntityData
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(MobileServiceClient.DefaultDatabasePath, "azureSyncDatabase.db");
        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);
        store.DefineTable<T>();

        await _mobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new SyncHandler(_mobileService));
    }
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496043/azure-app-service-limits-body-size-to-64kb

Comment: Hey @Krumelur! This makes sense, but I'm not sure how to configure the backend, because I used Azure Easy Tables and I didn't manually create the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Mobile Apps backend is just a Node.js site that is pre-configured for you.  You can use the App Service Editor to see the code behind the scenes.

Look at the [Azure Mobile Apps Node.js HOWTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk) - it contains a section on making the size of the payload accepted bigger.  Just implement the change in the App Service Editor and restart the service.  Look for HOWTO: Handle Large File Uploads

If you are doing an insert, your data should not be that big though.  Do not insert images or other larger items into a table - that's a bad practice.