# Node + react js increse upload file size in post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, filesize

how can i increse upload file size in Node + react

i am successfully uploading csv file for 100k counts (14 mb)

but for 500K or 1000K . application crashes ..

i saw similar post , but that using express js to limit filesize

I am using fetch

```
fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
            'user_token': sessionStorage.getItem('token'),
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
        },          
        body: JSON.stringify({
        'uploadedData': this.state.uploadedData,
        }),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {

    })
}
```

i have tried to remove

```
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Content-Type':'application/json',
```

or use

```
'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
```

But that doesnot work

I am using laravel server , I also increase upload file size limit on php.ini .. still not result

is there any way to increase file size ??

Comment: Can you share the crash data? Is the failure on the server side?

Comment: error "aw snap , something went wrong" .. no detail coming

Comment: try adding this to the then block immediately after the fetch .. `if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  } else { 
    throw new Error('Something went wrong');
  }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js: how to limit the HTTP request size and upload file size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049993/node-js-how-to-limit-the-http-request-size-and-upload-file-size)

Comment: its using express js to set file limit

Answer (score 1):

Try this in expressjs to increase limit of size

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
```