# How to limit image size on server side without downloading?

Tags: node.js, image

Right now I am checking the file size and blocking any further action.

```
if (req.file.size > 4000000) {
          return "Image too big";
}
```

But the file is still downloaded. Sure I can delete it but how can I prevent the file from being downloaded by the server if it's over a certain size without downloading the file?

EDIT: The reason body-parser limit didn't work for me is because I'm using multer.

Solution:

```
const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/", limits: { fileSize: 4000000 } });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js: how to limit the HTTP request size and upload file size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049993/node-js-how-to-limit-the-http-request-size-and-upload-file-size)

Comment: I tried 
`app.use(express.json({ limit: "3mb" }));
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "3mb", extended: false }));

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "3mb", extended: true }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "3mb" }));`
But it didn't prevent the file being downloaded.

Comment: It should only download first 3MB (up to your limit) of the file then it will stop the request.